# Time complexity of algorithm computing averages

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, analysis-of-algorithms

I am new, and wanted to see if someone can help me.

> What is the running time of your algorithm (below) with respect to the variable $n$? Give an upper bound of the form ${\cal O}(f(n))$ and a lower bound of the form $\Omega(g(n)).$ Can you characterize the asymptotic running time by by some $\Theta(h(n))$?

The algorithm:

> Input: $A[1 \ldots n]$ array of floating point numbers
>
> Output: Two dimensional array $M,$ such that $M[i][j]$ is the average of $A[i],\ldots, A[j],$ for all $i \le j,$ 0 for all $i>j.$

```
for i := 1 to n do
  for j := 1 to n do
      if i > j then M[i][j] := 0
      else
          sum := 0;
          d := j-i+1;
          l := i;
          r := j;
          do 
              sum := sum + a[l];
              l++; 
          while (l <= r)
          M[i][j] := sum / d;
      print M[i][j]; 
  end for
end for
```

Can someone give me an upper and lower bound?

I guess the algorithm complexity is ${\cal O}(n^3)$ on average, because of the quadratic complexity of the 2 for loops and the inner while loop which takes $O(n)$ time, which has the overhand over the assignments operations which takes $O(1)$ time.

But what is the upper and lower bound? And asymptotic running time by by some $\Theta(h(n))$?

Comment: I suggest you post this on http://area51.stackexchange.com and http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: @KirthiRaman cstheory.SE is for *research-level* questions in computer science. This is an undergrad-level question. I guess by area51.SE you mean [this propsal  for cs.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science). Unfortunately, [cs.SE is private beta right now](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). They say it will go public in about 5-6 days from now I guess.

Comment: This question was already asked on cstheory.se; it was quickly closed for being off-topic.

Comment: Also asked and closed on MathOverflow.

Comment: I do not understand if this is a forum or i do not know what. The idea behind a forum is to develop a discussion as I think i tried to make. I just try to get rid with my problem and i tried to develop a solution by my own, the algorithm and the identification of the complexity. BUT i see that it is like i asked something terrible. I do not pretend u give me an answer on this task, because at the end i should undestand what is behind and be able to solve it by my own. I just ask to help me to understand the right approach, the idea which is behind and give me some hints, like Johannes made.

Answer (score 1):

As you states, the algorithm runs in $O(n^3)$, which is actually the upper bound for the reasons you described.

To find a lower bound, note that it sufficient to find out the running time of the body of the inner for loop in terms of $i$, $j$ and $n$ (in fact, you will find that $n$ does not matter - why?). Denote this by $r(n,i,j)$. Then the running time of the whole algorithm is $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n r(n,i,j) + \Omega(n)$, where the final $\Omega(n)$ comes from the time required for executing the for loops.

The asymptotic running time will, of course, lie between the upper and the lower bound. In this example, it will be obvious as soon as you know the lower bound.

Comment: Thank u for the answer...
hmm so if u say that the lower bound is related to the work inside the second for loop, i can observe that in half of the cases there's just an assignment which has constant complexity O(1). In the other half there's another loop which iteration depends on i and j value (so this is why u say that n does no matter. Right?).
In the average case it will be executed n/2 time, because of the condition i gave i<=j and it is linear dependent of n. Am i right? .... what's then the lower bound of this algorithm? ..

Comment: Yes, Johannes the method and the right approach. This is my last exam at the university and i have not the possibility to frequent my lessons, so i need to learn it by my own. Anyway if the inner work of the inner loop takes Ω(n) time and the 2 for loops takes O(n^2) time, guess the overall running time is Ω(n^3) which is also the lower bound. Do not know if i am on the right way :)

Comment: If it is $n/2$ in the average case, that means that $r \in \Omega(n)$ (i.e., the inner part of the for loops runs in $\Omega(n)$). Hence, the overall algorithm is in ...?

Comment: PS: This looks very much like homework, so I would rather not give the answer directly, but help you in learning the methods instead.

Comment: PPS: You can just edit your post instead of writing an answer.

Comment: "This is my last exam at the university"?  Wait... this is an EXAM problem?

Comment: No...not an exam problem....it is just an exercise....

Comment: I just want to ask what is wrong on my question. If forum exists for developing discussions, or trying to get hints on some problems so my question is right, because i do not pretend that u give me an answer, just give me hints and an idea to approach the task. As u see in my topic i have not given a problem and waiting for answer, i have tried to do it by my own, i developed this algorithm to compute the average of an array of elements which populates at the end a two dimensional matrix and now i try to identify an upper and lower bound.